# Unrecognized author

Tags: git, github

When I commit a file from Git Bash on my computer and push it on GitHub, I am not recognized as the author of the commit:

[image: Unrecognized author]

When pointing on the question mark, here is the message displayed:

> Unrecognized author. If this is you, make sure the email address you used to commit is associated with your account. You can add emails to your account in Settings.

Problem is I checked several times and I can assure you the two e-mail addresses corresponds.

> git config --global user.email

Displays the exact same e-mail address given in [Email settings of GitHub](https://github.com/settings/emails).

I use Windows 7 and I connect with SSH to the remote repository.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `git show` or `git show <commit-SHA>` for checking if your commit's author email is correct. If not, use `git config user.email "<your-email>"` as you may have changed that setting for that particular repo, despite your global config.

Comment: Thanks, `git show` didn't display the correct e-mail address and I used your command to change it. It Works.

Answer (score 25):

To set up the right name and email for your future commits:

```
git config --global user.name "John Doe"
git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

---

If you want **to fix** your previous unauthored commits, follow the [Github documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/):

1. Do `git show` and remember the email which were used:

   ```
   $ git show
   commit ca44c93b9433346f858676a8f1b83f3d9757ec65
   Author: John Doe <johndoe@johndoes-MacBook-Pro.local>
   ```
2. Create a bare clone of your repository:

   ```
   git clone --bare https://github.com/user/repo.git
   ```
3. Replace `OLD_EMAIL`,  `CORRECT_NAME` and `CORRECT_EMAIL`, then `cd` to your repository and paste the script.  Press enter.

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   git filter-branch --env-filter '

   OLD_EMAIL="your-old-email@example.com"
   CORRECT_NAME="Your Correct Name"
   CORRECT_EMAIL="your-correct-email@example.com"

   if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
   then
       export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
       export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
   fi
   if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
   then
       export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
       export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
   fi
   ' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
   ```
4. Force push to Github:

   ```
   git push --force --tags origin 'refs/heads/*'
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, worked for me and got my GitHub stats back to normal.

Comment: Bumping this as recommended answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the solution.

Basically, `git config --global user.email` contained the good e-mail address but `git config user.email` did not.

So I just had to modify the local one and it worked. Still don't know why though.

Comment: You've probably run `git config user.email` on that repo before making that commit. Or run `git config --global user.email` _after_ that commit.